# Updating a dataframe utilizing conditions and another dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two dataframes, `df1` and `df2`. `df1` is my order dataframe and `df2` is my stock dataframe. I want to update stock according to the orders. If the order is type 1, it should reduce the stock with shorter time number and if type is 2, it should reduce the one with higher time number. Here is an example:

```
data1 = {"id": [128, 128, 128, 128, 128, 128, 128, 128, 128, 128, 128, 128, 128], "type": [1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1], "amount" :[2, 3, 54, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2]}

df1 = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data1)

data2 = {"id": [128, 128, 128], "quantity": [54, 72, 151], "time" :[176, 336, 346] }
df2 = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data2)


def availability_array(disp, orders, kind):
    if kind == 2:
        result = disp[::-1]
        
        for i in range(len(disp)):
            if disp[i] < orders:
                result[i] = 0
                orders -= disp[i]
            else:
                result[i] = disp[i] - orders       
        return result[::-1]
    else:
        result = np.copy(disp[::-1])
    
        for i in range(len(disp)):
            if disp[i] < orders:
                result[i] = 0
                orders -= disp[i]
            else:
                result[i] = disp[i] - orders
                break
        return result

def updating_df2(ids, quantity):
    article_ = pd.Index(df2['id'])
    index = article_.get_loc(ids)
    index_start =index.start
    index_end = index.stop
    index= np.arange(index_start, index_end)

    for i in range(len(index)):
        to_replace = df2.at[index[i],'quantity']
        df2.replace(to_replace= to_replace, value= quantity[i], inplace=True)

    return df2



for i in range(len(df1)):
    x = df1["id"][i]
    kind = df1["type"][i]
    y = df2[df2["id"] == x].quantity 
    batch_nr = df2[df2["id"] == x].quantity
    z = df1["amount"][i] 
   
    result  = availability_array(y.values, z, kind)
    df2 = updating_df2(x, result)
```

Using this code I get this results

| id | quantity | time |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 128 | 0 | 176 |
| 128 | 52 | 336 |
| 128 | 0 | 346 |

But the results I get is:

| id | quantity | time |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 128 | 36 | 176 |
| 128 | 72 | 336 |
| 128 | 97 | 346 |

This result is because the id 128, type 2, amount 54 should be taking out from the stock with higher time. If the stock is smaller than order then it takes out from the the next stock.

Answer (score 0):

One approach would be to add indicator values.

Set `1` to the lowest time per `id` and `2` to the highest time per `id` (Note this will not work for an id with a single entry or only a single time value)

[`idxmax`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.idxmax.html#pandas-dataframe-idxmax) + [`idxmin`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.idxmin.html#pandas-dataframe-idxmin) + [`loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html#pandas-dataframe-loc):

```
g = df2.groupby('id')['time']
df2.loc[g.idxmin().values, 'type'] = 1
df2.loc[g.idxmax().values, 'type'] = 2
```

`df2`:

```
    id  quantity  time  type
0  128        54   176   1.0
1  128        72   336   NaN
2  128       151   346   2.0
```

Then get the total amounts from `df1` [`groupby sum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.sum.html#pandas-core-groupby-groupby-sum):

```
totals = df1.groupby(['id', 'type'])['amount'].sum()
```

`totals`:

```
id   type
128  1       18
     2       54
Name: amount, dtype: int64
```

[`join`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html#pandas-dataframe-join) with `df2`:

```
df2 = df2.join(totals, on=['id', 'type']).fillna(0, downcast='infer')
```

```
    id  quantity  time  type  amount
0  128        54   176     1      18
1  128        72   336     0       0
2  128       151   346     2      54
```

Then subtract `amount` from `quantity` and [`drop`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html#pandas-dataframe-drop) temp columns:

```
df2['quantity'] = df2['quantity'] - df2['amount']
df2 = df2.drop(['type', 'amount'], axis=1)
```

`df2`:

```
    id  quantity  time
0  128        36   176
1  128        72   336
2  128        97   346
```

---

All Together:

```
g = df2.groupby('id')['time']
df2.loc[g.idxmin().values, 'type'] = 1
df2.loc[g.idxmax().values, 'type'] = 2
df2 = (
    df2.join(df1.groupby(['id', 'type'])['amount'].sum(), on=['id', 'type'])
        .fillna(0, downcast='infer')
)
df2['quantity'] = df2['quantity'] - df2['amount']
df2 = df2.drop(['type', 'amount'], axis=1)
```

`df2`:

```
    id  quantity  time
0  128        36   176
1  128        72   336
2  128        97   346
```